# How to serve static files using Klein.php

Tags: php, routes, klein-mvc

I'm trying to serve static files located in `/web` directory using `Klein.php` like this :

```
$klein->respond('/web/[*]', function($request, $response, $service, $app) {
    return $service->file(__DIR__ . $request->pathname());
});
```

But receive this error on the terminal

```
[Sat Jun 14 18:14:25 2014] PHP Fatal error: 
 Call to undefined method Klein\ServiceProvider::file()
 in /home/youssef/Desktop/gestion-stages/front_controller.php on line 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$klein->respond('/web/[*]', function($request, $response, $service, $app) {
    return $response->file(__DIR__ . $request->pathname());
});
```

Looks like file() is a method of Response, rather than ServiceProvider:

https://github.com/chriso/klein.php/blob/737e7268f5c3fdc6d6f1371cb2ee0264892e8540/src/Klein/Response.php#L85

Klein is a great little framework, but I do find I have to dig into the source occasionally.  On the bright side, the source has great comments and clean code.  It's the sort of project the reading of which makes you a better programmer.

The main dev is usually pretty good about responding to issues on GitHub if you have trouble with anything: https://github.com/chriso/klein.php/issues?state=open

### Another Option

One final thing I should note.  If this is what you're really trying to do, rather than a simplified example, you may be able to accomplish the same thing with Apache mod_rewrite, or the equivalent in Nginx, and have better performance, since you're not executing any PHP code at that point.  On the other hand, if you want to do something more advanced, like checking the user's login credentiails before deciding whether to serve the file, or serve files outside your document root, the way you're doing it is probably spot on.

I'm not very good at writing mod_rewrite rules, but I think you could do something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/web/(.+) /your/desired/path/$1 [R,L]
```

assuming the destination is web-accessible.  Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html

Or, if it's not web-accessible, it looks like you could setup an alias:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside

I haven't tested the rewrite rule, and I've never messed with aliases, but I think those will do the trick.  Of course, this all assumes you are using Apache, have access to Apache configs, or at least .htacces config, and that you don't have a much grander scheme in mind than simply serving static files.  I'm also assuming you are somewhat familiar with Apache config in general, which I know not everyone is.  However, if that seems like it might work, give it a try.  Or feel free to ignore it.

Comment: It was actually a mistake in the klein's README file that led me to use $service instead of $response.

Comment: I see you opened a bug report on GitHub to get the mistake fixed.  Thanks for that! https://github.com/chriso/klein.php/issues/207

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this simple snippet with the PHP built-in server :

```
<?php
// before creating a Klein inctance
if (preg_match('#^/web/#', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
}
```

And of course the server is run like this

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t . front_controller.php
```

Comment: is the first snippet the content of front_controller.php or did you insert that somewhere else in your codebase?